# Clickhouse select query without cache

Tags: clickhouse

Is there any "without cache" option in clickhouse select query?

I want to check run-time performance of clickhouse without cache.

I expect options like SQL_NO_CACHE in mysql.

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE * FROM table WHERE search= 'keyword';
```

Comment: what goal you try achieve when "not use cache"? 
decrease memory usage? 
more precise for measurement of query performance?

Comment: @Slach Yes, it's for precise measurement of query performance

Comment: @hyeon in this case vladimir right, just use https://clickhouse.yandex/docs/en/operations/settings/settings/#setting-use_uncompressed_cache
and https://clickhouse.yandex/docs/en/operations/server_settings/settings/#server-settings-uncompressed_cache_size

Comment: @Slach Thank you

Answer (score 5):

The cache reset is done in two steps:

1. reset the OS [PageCache](https://www.tecmint.com/clear-ram-memory-cache-buffer-and-swap-space-on-linux/)

```sh
sync; echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

2. reset mark-cache in CH using [DROP MARK CACHE](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/sql_reference/statements/system/#query_language-system-drop-mark-cache)

```sql
SYSTEM DROP MARK CACHE
```

Comment: ClickHouse also gives the ability to drop uncompressed cache, ie `SYSTEM DROP UNCOMPRESSED CACHE`.

Answer (score 0):

I think echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches is not a good idea.
As when ck starts, the primary key is cached in memory
so you can use settings min_bytes_to_use_direct_io=1